# "Ten million questions" announcement breaks the navigation tabs in mobile view

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, system-message

See the picture below:

[image]

The issue seems to be:

```
.nav li.current a {
    color: #fffdff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Also on Meta.SE: [System message breaks mobile site layout](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250411). Selected menu item _is_ supposed to have that style, but it's not supposed to be pushed down to white background.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's a simple CSS fix, from [my answer to the meta.SE report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264134):

```css
.nav { clear: both }
```

This rule will cause the navbar to be properly pushed down below the announcement.  Here's a pair of "before and after" screenshots showing the effect of this fix:

[image: Screenshot of Stack Overflow mobile view with CSS bug]
   
[image: Screenshot of fixed Stack Overflow mobile view]

Comment: I guess the simplest fix would be to get rid of it.  "Really. Clever. Copywriting." is just so, so lame.  The world is drenched in silly advertising messages, and it is particularly annoying where the ad agency / whoever is trying to be "clever".

Comment: `#system-message { visibility: collapse; }`